# How to get the index of a tr when traversing the table and when adding a new element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm traversing a table with jquery, but I want to get the index of the tr at specific moments of the tranvers table:

```
$('table#tabla_materia tr').each(function()
{
   if(typeof ($(this).find('input.cep').val()) !== 'undefined'){


  // get the index here
  rowIndex
  }


// get the index of the new element
var nuevoRegistro = tbl_materia.insertRow(rowIndex+1);
nuevoRegistro.setAttribute('class', 'cep');

}
```

Can you help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read either [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex) property of the HTMLTableRowElement, or use `index` parameter passed to [`$.fn.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) callback.

```
$('table#tabla_materia tr').each(function (index) {
    console.log(index, this.rowIndex);
    // ...
});
```

Well, to be *exact*, `index` in `$.fn.each` callback is actually the index of the table row element in corresponding jQuery collection. However if you don't have nested tables this index will correspond to the actual [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex) property.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I get que index outside the $('table#tabla_materia tr').each(function (index) { for new elements added

Comment: Well if you use `insertRow` like you are doing then new row index is `rowIndex+1`.

Comment: But now I'm doing the insert row after the function $('table#tabla_materia tr').each(function() 

I'm using this ptypeRowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index(); but i'm getting -1

Comment: Can you post your entire code, not clear when you are trying to get new index.